# File Manager won't connect to sFTP Server

Tags: 14.04, ssh, sftp

Using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Until this morning, I had been accessing files through the file manager from a sFTP server by placing "sftp://servername/directory" into the Server Address field.

However, since this morning the "Connect" button is grayed-out and the dialog informs me that "This file server type is not recognized." 
I have attempted to follow other suggestions that I have found, including replacing "sftp" with "ssh", but that didn't do anything. 
As a work around I have installed *sshfs*, but I would still like to know how to get the native functionality back.

Comment: Is the server up? Can you use the command line to connect top it via ssh or sftp?

Comment: I can connect to server using "ssh" on the command line, which I often do for other purposes (testing, etc...).